# React - Adding a property to an object inside of array in component's state

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I am fetching an array of objects in the state, and I am trying to add a property to each of these objects.
The problem is I can see my property being added to each of the objects but when I mapping through all these objects and trying to `console.log` it I'm getting `undefined`

Adding a property

```
addFavourites() {
        let data = this.state.data.map((e) => {
            e.favourite = false;
            return e;
        });
        return data;
    }
```

```
state = {
        data: []
    }
```

addFavourites's called here:

```
getItem = () => {
        this.service
            .mergeData()
            .then((body) => {
                this.setState({
                    data: body
                },
                () => {
                    this.addFavourites();
                },
                () => {
                    this.dataToFilter();
                });
            });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getItem();
    }
```

In render function I see all my objects including favourite

```
console.log(data.map((e) => e));
```

But this gives an array of undefined

```
console.log(data.map((e) => e.favourite));
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Would you provide more code how `addFavorite` is called, when the state is saved, and where you are logging?

Comment: I edit my code, is it ok?

Comment: You call `this.addFavourites();` but returned data from `addFavourites()` never get stored in any variable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, welcome! You should have probably made it more clear that this question is about React.

Now to the answer, every state modification would be made using `setState`, so your `addFavourites` function should be like this:

```
addFavourites() {
    let data = this.state.data.map((e) => {
        e.favourite = false;
        return e;
    });
    this.setState({ data: data });
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I get know, forgot to store this to the state. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. You should mark the answer if it answered your question.